# Use the default startActivity() and onBackPressed() animations from specific Android versions?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-navigation

Is there a way to use the default `startActivity()` and `onBackPressed()` animations from a specific Android version?

Different versions of Android have slightly different default animations and I would like to keep it consistent across all versions.

For example API 31's default `startActivity()` animation pops the activity from the center of the screen and `onBackPressed()` slides it down and disappears. Where as in API 33 the default `startActivity()` animation slides in from right-to-left and `onBackPressed()` slides out from left-to-right.

Comment: They aren't specific to an Android version - different manufacturers can also customize what they use by default.

Comment: @ianhanniballake  I see. The above is all from Pixel phones. Are you saying it is not possible to tap into to one of those animations and always use it then?

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

Starting from API level 5 you can call overridePendingTransition immediately to specify an explicit transition animation

```
startActivity();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
```

res/anim/fade_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

res/anim/fade_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/anticipate_interpolator"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" android:duration="500" />
</set>
```